# How to get original exception from ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

If a template causes an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception to be raised, the original exception is swallowed up by ActionView and turned into an `ActionView::Template::Error`.

It seems that in Rails 5 there was an [original_exception](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/actionview/5.0.0.1/ActionView/Template/Error#original_exception-instance_method) method but that appears to be gone in Rails 6.

I'd like to be able to inspect the cause of the `ActionView::Template::Error` so I can show better contextual errors.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you catch the `ActionView::Template::Error`, there should be a `#cause` method defined on it which returns the original exception. Example:

```
begin
  begin
    raise ArgumentError
  rescue
    raise RuntimeError
  end
rescue => e
  puts "#{ e } caused by #{ e.cause }"
end
```

prints

```
RuntimeError caused by ArgumentError
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Inspecting e.backtrace may be helpful for you too!